# Oracle - SUM of multiples columns and lines

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables

***n_station*** and ***val_horaires***

[image: n_station_table] [image: val_horaires]

One station has multiple val_horaires and they are link via `SUBSTR(code_mesure,1,4) = code_stas`

The following query is giving me all the stations from a specific group with all the value between 2 dates

```
select
  m.code_mesure,s.code_stas,s.nom_station, s.riviere_bassin, s.lambert_x, s.lambert_y,
  m.date_val_hor, m.h_01,m.h_02,m.h_03,m.h_04,m.h_05,m.h_06,m.h_07,m.h_08,m.h_09,m.h_10,m.h_11,m.h_12,m.h_13,m.h_14,m.h_15,m.h_16,m.h_17,m.h_18,m.h_19,m.h_20,m.h_21,m.h_22,m.h_23,m.h_24
from HYDRO.n_station s
join
(
  select 
    substr(vm.code_mesure,1,4) as code_stas, vm.*
  from HYDRO.val_horaires vm
  where code_mesure in (select code_mesure from HYDRO.GROUPE_MESURE where HYDRO.GROUPE_MESURE.CODE_GROUPE = 'TELEMP')
  AND vm.date_val_hor between '12/12/2016 16:00' AND '14/12/2016 17:00'
) m 
on m.code_stas = s.code_stas
where s.code_stas in (select SUBSTR(code_mesure,1,4) from HYDRO.GROUPE_MESURE where CODE_GROUPE = 'TELEMP')
AND s.lambert_x > 0 AND s.lambert_Y > 0
```

Result of above query

```
code_mesure code_stas nom_station           riviere_bassin          lambert_X lambert_Y date_val_hor      h_01 h_02 h_03 h_04 h_05 ...................................
70480015    7048    EREZEE                  OURTHE                  236667  109356  12/12/2016 00:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
70480015    7048    EREZEE                  OURTHE                  236667  109356  13/12/2016 00:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,5 0   0,1 0,4 0,1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
70480015    7048    EREZEE                  OURTHE                  236667  109356  14/12/2016 00:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
60480015    6048    RACHAMPS-NOVILLE        OURTHE                  251592  86756   12/12/2016 00:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
60480015    6048    RACHAMPS-NOVILLE        OURTHE                  251592  86756   13/12/2016 00:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,7 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,1 0   0   0   0   0
60480015    6048    RACHAMPS-NOVILLE        OURTHE                  251592  86756   14/12/2016 00:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
```

I am now trying to get for each stations the SUM of all `h_01,h_02,...h_24` for each line and also SUM those 3 lines togethers. Numbers below 0 should not be used (eg: `-9999`)

In this case the result would be

```
code_mesure code_stas nom_station           riviere_bassin          lambert_X lambert_Y Sum  LastValue
    70480015    7048    EREZEE                  OURTHE                  236667  109356  0.11 0
    60480015    6048    RACHAMPS-NOVILLE        OURTHE                  251592  86756   0.8  0
```

*One last thing :*

If the start date is `12/12/2016 16h00` - The value in the row with the date `12/12/2016` should only be used starting from `h_16` to `h_24`

if the end date is `14/12/2016 17:00` - The value in the row with the date `14/12/2016` shoul only be used starting from `h_01` to `h_17`

Comment: That's not good way of storing data. If you need to filter by hour it looks you need to `unpivot` h1 - h24 to obtain row for each hour and then go with `sum`. Before `unpivot` you probably need to `group by code_mesure, code_stas, nom_station, riviere_bassin, lambert_X, lambert_Y`

Comment: @Kacper I know that is a terrible way of storing data but I cannot change this database even if I want to. Could you please provide an example of how to use `unpivot` ? I am not so good in queries

Comment: Hints: to sum across columns it's as simple as `col1 + col2` (remembering that if at least one of the column values is null, the result of the sum will also be null, so you need to cater for that). To sum across rows, take a look at the SUM aggregate query. Try working out your query for yourself (you'll learn more that way) and if you get stuck, please update your question with what you've tried so far. You may need to have a CASE statement to decide which columns to sum. Although, having said all that, Kacper's suggestion of unpivoting before doing the sum across rows would be easier.

Comment: @Boneist it is simply h1+h2+.. but for such way to apply condition for date with hours we need dynamic query I'm afraid

Comment: @Kacper no, not necessarily. But the resultant case statement would be quite large, taking account of the start date being on the 1st hour, 2nd hour etc and same for the end date. Unpivoting as you suggested is the way to go, I think.

Comment: @Kacper I am calling this query from Java application. I was thinking getting first all station and then iterate them in java and getting the values I need with some java algorithm. I just think that it will be slower like this

Comment: @Boneist Same comment

Comment: @Weedoze I highly recommend you research [`UNPIVOT`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1#unpivot). By doing that, you can then convert the date from the row + the hour from the column into an actual date. Then you can join those rows based on the vm.date_val_hor column. Btw, if you have a date column and you want to compare it to a string-that's really a date, you should use `to_date()` to explicitly convert it into a date, rather than relying on the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter. You could get strange bugs as a result.

Comment: If you're calling it from Java you can go for 3 queries. First day is `h16+..+h24` middle part is `select sum (nvl(h1,0) + .. + nvl(h24,0)) from tab group by` and last day is `h1+..+h17` but I would go for `unpivot` and do it with one query.

Comment: @Boneist I have no idea how to work with `unpivot` could you please provide an example with my current query ?

Comment: @Weedoze there are plenty of examples of how to work with unpivot both in stack overflow and across the rest of the internet. If you aren't sure how to work with it, study some of these examples. Test them out by taking a row from your table and applying the upivot to 2 or 3 of your hour columns. That'll hopefully help you learn what it's doing and how you should use it.

Comment: @Boneist Ok I will try something. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GREATEST()` to restrict the numbers to positive values then add the values to combine across columns and use the `SUM()` aggregate function to combine rows with a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
WITH bounds ( start_time, end_time ) AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-12-12 16:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2016-12-14 17:00:00' FROM DUAL
)
select
  m.code_mesure,
  s.code_stas,
  s.nom_station,
  s.riviere_bassin,
  s.lambert_x,
  s.lambert_y,
  SUM(
      CASE WHEN m.date_val_hor +  1/24 BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.end_time THEN GREATEST( m.h_01, 0 ) ELSE 0 END 
    + CASE WHEN m.date_val_hor +  2/24 BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.end_time THEN GREATEST( m.h_02, 0 ) ELSE 0 END 
    + CASE WHEN m.date_val_hor +  3/24 BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.end_time THEN GREATEST( m.h_03, 0 ) ELSE 0 END 
    ...
    + CASE WHEN m.date_val_hor + 24/24 BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.end_time THEN GREATEST( m.h_24, 0 ) ELSE 0 END 
  ) AS h_sum,
  MAX(
    CASE EXTRACT( HOUR FROM b.end_time )
      WHEN  0 THEN m.h_01 -- Possibly m.h_24
      WHEN  1 THEN m.h_02 -- Possibly m.h_01
      WHEN  2 THEN m.h_03 -- Possibly m.h_02
      ...
      WHEN 22 THEN m.h_23 -- Possibly m.h_22
              ELSE m.h_24 -- Possibly m.h_23
    END
  ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY m.date_val_hor ) AS last_hour_value
from bounds b
     cross join
     HYDRO.n_station s
     join
     ( select substr(vm.code_mesure,1,4) as code_stas,
              vm.*
       from   HYDRO.val_horaires vm
              join
              bounds b
              ON ( vm.date_val_hor between TRUNC( b.start_time ) AND TRUNC( b.end_time ) )
       where  code_mesure in (select code_mesure
                              from   HYDRO.GROUPE_MESURE
                              where  HYDRO.GROUPE_MESURE.CODE_GROUPE = 'TELEMP')
      ) m 
      on m.code_stas = s.code_stas
where s.code_stas in ( select SUBSTR(code_mesure,1,4)
                       from   HYDRO.GROUPE_MESURE
                       where  CODE_GROUPE = 'TELEMP' )
AND s.lambert_x > 0 AND s.lambert_Y > 0
GROUP BY
  m.code_mesure,
  s.code_stas,
  s.nom_station,
  s.riviere_bassin,
  s.lambert_x,
  s.lambert_y
```

Comment: Everything fine but date is stored as day and values for hours are in columns so your condition `between TIMESTAMP '2016-12-12 16:00:00'
                                  AND TIMESTAMP '2016-12-14 17:00:00'` ignores hours. Query needs unpivot or horrible case

Comment: @Kacper is right + I need only one row with the value from all the dates. In your query I will have multiple times the same stations with different dates

Comment: @Weedoze Updated to ignore hours outside the bounds.

Comment: @MT0 This seems to work like a charm + It is fast ! Is there a way to get the latest value in the same query ? The query you provided will get the value from the last 24h. I also need the last hour value - If we are the 15/12/2016 7:30 I need the `h_06` from the row with date `15/12/2016`. If you have sometimes to help me with this one it would be great. Anyway thanks for your answer !

Comment: @Weedoze Added something that should give you the last hour value - but I've not tested it as I have no data.

Comment: @MT0 I can confirm that it works ! Thanks you so much !